# Get counting data by comma-separated value field in Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch

Need Help.

I have data in elasticsearch, field "interests" like this:

{
"interests": "A,C,D,E"
},
{
"interests": "B,C,D"
},
{
"interests": "A,B,C,D,E"
},
{
"interests": "D,E"
}

I want to get data like this:
{
"key": "A",
"doc_count": 2
},
{
"key": "B",
"doc_count": 2
},
{
"key": "C",
"doc_count": 3
},
{
"key": "D",
"doc_count": 4
},
{
"key": "E",
"doc_count": 3
}

what steps should I take.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple [`terms` aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) should do the job:

```
POST test/_search
{
  "aggs": {
    "interests": {
      "terms": { "field": "interests" }
    }
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Since the `interests` field is a single string you first need to split the contained values. If you don't want to reindex all your data, you can achieve this with an ingest pipeline that updates the data in-place.

First create the pipeline using a [`split` processor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/split-processor.html) like this:

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/splitter
{
  "processors": [
    {
      "split": {
        "field": "interests",
        "separator": ","
      }
    },
    {
      "trim": {
        "field": "interests"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Then update your index using that new pipeline, like this:

```
POST your-index/_update_by_query?pipeline=splitter
```

Your `interests` field will be changed from this

```
    {
      "interests" : "A, C, D, E"
    },
```

To this:

```
    {
      "interests" : [
        "A",
        "C",
        "D",
        "E"
      ]
    },
```

Comment: Thank you Sir. But how if data like this :

{ "interests": "Play Music,Dance,Trip a Vacation" }, { "interests": "Trip a Vacation,Sport & Music,Play Music" }, { "interests": "Play Music" }, { "interests": "Trip a Vacation" }

Comment: Thank you Sir. 

But how if data like this : { "interests": "Play Music,Dance,Trip a Vacation" }, { "interests": "Trip a Vacation,Sport & Music,Play Music" }, { "interests": "Play Music" }, { "interests": "Trip a Vacation" }

Comment: Oh, actually, I didn't notice that everything was in the same string. You need to split those strings at indexing time

Comment: See my updated answer